# asp.net VB LoginStatus in master page results in two forms with runat=server

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET VB and built a simple login/register app. I was trying to add a loginStatus control to the master page but this results in error

```
A page can have only one server-side Form tag.
```

Are there any workarounds for that? And actually, why does loginStatus control requires to be in form anyway?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `Form` tag from your content page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since you are using web forms, you are required to only have one `<form runat="server">` in your page, but somehow you have two, or zero.  Get it back to one, and make sure all .NET controls are inside of it.  Obviously, the form should be defined in the master page.

Comment: But I have to have three forms because loginStatus needs to be in a master page, and pages themselves have a form in them

Comment: This will not work for ASP.NET web forms; you have to find another way to design the feature you want.  The one form rule was an explicit requirement from Microsoft.  Why do login status need to be a form?

Comment: That is what I do not get either - why does login status need a form. Well, thanks for the answer. Guess code the login/logout myself is the only possible solution.

Comment: All ASP.NET controls need to be in a form tag that has a runat="server".  This is the web forms model Microsoft created.